# ModuleNotFound Error: No module named 'sip' while install guidata package

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, package, pyqt5

i am trying to install guidata library for python 3.7 and PyQt5 but installation stopped with error No module named 'sip'

tried to install through py-charm got the same error,although  sip module already installed, trying pip install also the same error, tried to download master.zip folder and run setup.py  file also no success

i got the error ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'sip'

Answer (score 0):

installing version 1.7.5 instead the latest one 1.7.6 solving the issue.